Error Importrange Goes Horizontal not vertical (Google Sheet)
I Wanna Ask to solve the error when use google sheet importrange formula, the result goes horizontal not vertical.
Below my code
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1WwKDHs4iovQRDcQGU-5Tf8omCPm3LIFr_XI7x2-A6Ms";"kontrol TA!i22:i");"Select Col1 where Col1 is not Null")
and the result as image

Importrange result is vertical, is anyone know to solve ? thanks

Set the header to 0.
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1WwKDHs4iovQRDcQGU-5Tf8omCPm3LIFr_XI7x2-A6Ms";"kontrol TA!i22:i");"where Col1 is not Null",0)

